# C# Is there a way to search through all listview items with a textbox?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, listview, search

I have developed an application which populates a Listview through a SQL CE connection. I already have the insert, update and delete functions in it. The only thing that's left is the search function. I thought it was the easiest part, but I am searching for 2 days now and haven't found a good tutorial on this, so I thought someone on StackOverflow could help me.

I have managed to search through the first item (main item, "PrincipalID") and I also want to search through the subitems. What I want is like

```
Principal ID    Email Address                     Subject                  Filename
193490          test@test.com                     Exec OUT (report)        q9193.xls
153130          test@test.com                     Standard mail Report     q7389.xls
```

What I now have is that I can search for principal numbers, but what I also want is to search for words, for example if I type "test" in the textbox, that I will get the record with the Email Address = "test@test.com" on top, or what would be better is that it will only show that record and hide the rest and then if the textbox is empty, that it shows all the records again.

So basically I want to search the WHOLE listview for the string that is typed in the search textbox.

Hopefully someone can help me,

I will appreciate it from the bottom of my heart.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `ListView.FindItemWithText`?

Comment: I did that, but I only got it to work with the first "main" item column "Principal ID"

Answer (score 0):

Try using this C# code or something similar to extract the listview items that match your string parameter.

```
    public void SearchInListView(ListView myListView, string searchThis) 
    {
            if (searchThis != "") 
            {
                foreach (ListViewItem lvItem in myListView.Items) 
                {
                    foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem lvSubItem in lvItem.SubItems) 
                    {
                        if (lvSubItem.Length >= 1) 
                        {
                            if (lvSubItem.ToLower().Contains(searchThis.ToLower())) 
                                //Mark this listview item in some way (e.g., change back color) or collect and return it
                            else 
                                //Mark this listview in a different way
                         }    
                    }
                 }
             }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TextChanged Event of a TextBox and if you search through the List you can bind only the Record you are searching for to the Grid.

So you can search for a specifik record in the List.

Answer (score 0):

you have to fire two queries....
if enter Textbox1.Text.IsNumber  then search by principle id 
else search by email
use like in query
maybe its work